# Meaning of 尖った道

Tags: meaning, words, adjectives, metaphor, collocations

What is the meaning of this expression? I know 尖った is an adjective that means "pointed, sharp", but I don't understand what a "pointed road" could be. I tried to google it but I only got 8 results, [all of them about a song](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E5%B0%96%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E9%81%93%22&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu6b64o6bTAhUGvhQKHU80DT8Q_AUIBSgA&biw=1600&bih=770&dpr=1), so it doesn't seem a common expression. Here's the sentence in which I found it:

> このガキ…　恐怖を感じる底を見出すコトができなかった。こいつは尖った道でしか歩けねェタイプだ。

Is it a metaphorical way to refer to a path that is hard to walk? Thank you for your help!

Comment: 尖った道って・・　https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_lGfq0HWzVg/maxresdefault.jpg　こんなのを想像します・・

Comment: ^ つまり・・一歩踏み外したら谷底へ真っ逆さま、みたいな、危険と隣り合わせの危なっかしい道、って感じの。。。（「穏やかな」「平和な」の反対の道なら「険しい道」とかになるような気も・・）

Comment: （ちなみに、「恐怖を感じる底」は「このガキが恐怖を感じ始める限界」って意味で、「恐怖を感じる底を見出‌​すコトができなかった」は、「いくら危ない‌​目に合わせても、このガキが怖がり始める限‌​界は見つからなかった」→「どんなに危険でも、このガキは（底なしに）怖がら‌​ない」って意味ですよね・・）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - このガキ
> - 恐怖｛きょうふ｝を感｛かん｝じる底｛そこ｝を見｛み｝出｛いだ｝すことができなかった。
> - 尖｛とが｝った道｛みち｝

It is a metaphorical way to refer to a world or a society that is hard to live.

「道｛みち｝」は、「人生｛じんせい｝街道｛かいどう｝」「世間｛せけん｝」あるいは「世｛よ｝の中｛なか｝」だと思｛おも｝います。「尖｛とが｝った」は、そのような意味｛いみ｝の「道｛みち｝」を比喩｛ひゆ｝的｛てき｝に形容｛けいよう｝しており、普通｛ふつう｝の精神｛せいしん｝を持｛も｝った人｛ひと｝なら「恐怖｛きょうふ｝を感｛かん｝じる」ような極悪｛ごくあく｝・非道｛ひどう｝、不合理｛ふごうり｝などが渦｛うず｝巻｛ま｝く様子｛ようす｝を表現｛ひょうげん｝しているように思｛おも｝います。この文脈｛ぶんみゃく｝では、「尖｛とが｝った」は、「まろやかな」「おだやかな」「平和｛へいわ｝な」のような形容詞｛けいようし｝の反意語｛はんいご｝ではないでしょうか。「このガキ（＝若者｛わかもの｝、若造｛わかぞう｝）」は、そのような「尖｛とが｝った世間｛せけん｝」でもまだ恐怖｛きょうふ｝の底｛そこ｝を感｛かん｝じていないのですから、本当｛ほんとう｝の悪｛わる｝ガキ、しかも腹｛はら｝のすわった悪｛わる｝ガキではないでしょうか。

I think 「道」, a road/way, means a "world" or "society" in this context. 「尖った」 meaning "sharp" describes the world or society metaphorically and figuratively, and I think the adjective "sharp" describes the brutality, heartlessness or irrationality of the world where normal person would feel fear. In this context, the adjective "sharp" is the antonym of the adjective such as "calm" "peaceful." "このガキ" meaning "this boy/youngster" may be a true naughty boy because he has not felt the bottom of the fear of the world yet.